# Prove a version of the mean value theorem where f is decreasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is a non-negative and decreasing function, and $h$ is continuous on a $[a,b]$, there there exists a point $c\in[a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^b f h = f(a)\int_a^c h$$

I know that the result is valid if we suppose that $f$ is increasing instead of assuming that is decreasing. So I guess the result that I'm trying to prove is almost there, but I can't see it.

Comment: $f(c)$ instead of $f(a)$?

Comment: No, actually what was wrong was the upper limit of integration of the second integral (should be c instead of b). The $f(a)$ is correct.

Comment: Can continuity of $f$ be presumed?

Comment: No. This problem is from Bartle's _Elements of Real Analysis_ and there is a similar result (without assuming f is continuous) with f increasing in $[a,b]$. That's why I think if I assume that result then I almost have the answer to my problem, but I'm not sure how. @MathematicsStudent1122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define

$$H(x) = \int_a^xh(t)\,dt.$$

Since $h$ is a continuous function, it follows that $H$ is differentiable and $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $H$

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x) \,dx= \int_a^bf(x)H'(x) \,dx=\int_a^bf \, dH.$$

Integrating by parts,

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x) \,dx= f(b)H(b)-f(a)H(a)-\int_a^bH \, df.$$

By the mean value theorem for integrals, there is a point $c \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x) \,dx= f(b)H(b)-f(a)H(a)-H(c)[f(b) - f(a)] \\=f(a)[H(c)-H(a)]+f(b)[H(b)-H(c)]\\=f(a)\int_a^{c}h(x) \, dx + f(b)\int_{c}^{b}h(x) \, dx.$$

Since $f$ is non-negative and decreasing, we can repeat the above derivation for the non-negative, decreasing function $\hat{f}$ given by

$$\hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases}f(x),  \,\,x \in [a,b) \\ 0, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = b\end{cases}$$ 
Hence,

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x) \,dx = \int_a^b\hat{f}(x)h(x) \,dx=f(a)\int_a^{c}h(x) \, dx.$$

The integrals involving $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are equal since changing the value of a function at a finite number of points does not change the value of a Riemann integral.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: You're welcome.  I know another way to prove this using partitions, but it's a lot messier.